# Determine if an open file has been modified in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

Is there any way to determine if an *open* file has been modified under POSIX? More specifically, how could I implement `is_modified()` below?

```
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "r+");

// do various things with f

if (is_modified(f))
    foo(f);
```

To provide some context, I'm writing a module in C that for every file needs to store its hash in a table. The interface provides wrappers for `fopen()` and `fclose()` and the hashing can be done when the file is closed. I found several approaches to do this, but neither is as efficient, clean or error-proof as I would love:

- Compute the hash of every file opened for writing.
- `fflush(f)` and check if timestamp has changed.
- Provide wrappers around `fwrite()`, `fprintf()`, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're the one that opens the file, why not simply keep track of whether you write to it or not?

Comment: For abstraction. This is supposed to be a module that gives out file handles in which clients can operate in any way they like. I wouldn't like to modify large parts of other code that operates on open files using standard library functions.

Comment: If you want to avoid other processes from concurrently modifying your files, take a look at [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).

Comment: No, inter-process locking is not an issue. And having many threads does not change anything in this situation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified above that it is safe to assume that a single process always uses the file.

Answer (score 6):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/File_modification_time#POSIX_utime.28.29

You can check the newest modification against the last modification with the stat() function.

Comment: That's a very simple solution, but it's susceptible to race conditions. After you get the modification time, and before you compare it and take any action, the file could have already been changed by another process/thread. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I entirely agree. I guess sleep() could be performed to wait the minimum time. In my opinion, this is a suboptimal solution to a problem architected as above.

Comment: I would recommend using `fstat()` instead of `stat()` because you already have the file descriptor available.

Comment: These are essentially my second solution above. I have to `fclose()` the file, do `stat()` and, if I detect a change, `fopen()` it, hash it and `fclose()` it again. Too inefficient.

Comment: `fstat()` comes close but check the answer from @JonathanLeffler.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're dishing out the handles with covers for `fopen()` and `fclose()`, you can record the result of `fstat()` when you open the file and again when you  are about to close the file, and compare the two.  If anything has changed, then you've got a positive change and you need to recompute the hash.  If nothing has changed, you can be moderately confident that you have the same file as before. If you need to eliminate that uncertainty, then you'll need to recompute the hash anyway, knowing that the file could be changed by another thread or another process while you are computing the hash.

Note that modern POSIX ([POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)) provides `struct stat` with time members:

- `struct timespec st_atim` - Last data access timestamp.
- `struct timespec st_mtim` - Last data modification timestamp.
- `struct timespec st_ctim` - Last file status change timestamp.

These provide for nanosecond resolution on the modification times.  It is likely that for reasons of backwards compatibility, there are macros such as:

```
#define st_atime st_atim.tv_sec
#define st_mtime st_mtim.tv_sec
#define st_ctime st_ctim.tv_sec
```

though AFAICS, the POSIX standard does not mandate this.  However, the `st_Xtime` names have been used since the beginning of (Unix) time - Version 7 Unix from 1978, and probably before - so systems are going to want to keep older code compiling and macros such as those provide a moderately painless way of doing so.

Comment: Unfortunately, `st_mtime` and the other members don't get updated while the file is open. So, this solution boils down to something like `fclose(); stat();` too.

Comment: The updates get scheduled (as long as the changes, if any, are `fflush()`d)...and if you're really worried, you can apply one of the O_xSYNC options to the file descriptor.  This program (with the appropriate headers) demos; tested MacOS X 10.7.2, but they're the expected results on any POSIX machine: `int main(void) { struct stat s1,s2; char name[] = "zzz"; FILE *fp; if ((fp = fopen(name, "w+")) != 0) { fstat(fileno(fp), &s1); sleep(5); putc('x', fp); fflush(fp); fstat(fileno(fp), &s2); printf("t1 %ld; t2 %ld\n", (long)s1.st_mtime, (long)s2.st_mtime); fclose(fp); unlink(name); } return(0); }`

Comment: Yes, an `fflush()` will update the timestamps, perhaps because they refer to the inode. I guess this is as far as one can go; the kernel certainly knows whether the file is dirty but doesn't seem to somehow export this information.

Comment: Remember that the kernel has no clue about what's in the `FILE` buffer until that is written to disk (that's why the `fflush()` is critical).  Note that the time stamps could change even though the contents do not; however, I don't think the contents can change unless the timestamps do - unless someone goes faking it with `utimes()` or `utimens()` etc.

Comment: I would expect the kernel to maintain some list of modified file blocks. That's impossible to fake and directly provides what I'm looking for. I guess I'll have to check the Linux sources to find out more.

Comment: Yes; the kernel also maintains a list of disk blocks in its disk buffer pool, and knows the state of each such block.  However, it still doesn't know about changes made in the application that are only recorded in the `FILE` structure (those which have not been flushed, where flushing can occur with an explicit `fflush()` or because the buffer fills, or because the file pointer moves (`fseek()` et al) and the contents is dirty).  Also, the kernel won't keep a record of which blocks were modified but have been flushed from the kernel buffer pool.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use kqueue notification system to receive notifications when somebody changes the file, and then invalidate/reload your hash entries

man 2 kqueue

http://blog.julipedia.org/2004/10/example-of-kqueue.html

Comment: That's interesting, but: a) means that _every_ write will generate an event; b) since `kevent()` blocks, I need at least two threads. Correct?

Comment: a) yep, but you can always amortize it with queueing events for specific period and then sending them to the other thread in bulks b) yep, you will need second thread to wait for events