# Cross-platform way to determine if file has been edited?

Tags: c

I am writing a cross-platform (big 3 - Linux, MAC, Windows) backup program, so I need to know if a file has been edited since last time. My plan is to save the last save time in a file and check the real situation of a folder against the data in the file to determine which files need to be backed up or updated.

I would like to avoid methods that require a lot of processing power (like `diff`, or counting bytes).

In [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628198/determine-if-an-open-file-has-been-modified-in-c), people suggested to use `fstat()`, but that solution would be a last resort for me because I was hoping for a cross-platform solution that can be solved with pure C. As far as I know, `fstat` is a (2), and in my man page it appears as (1), which (to my understanding) means that it is a system function in Linux and isn't a part of the standard C library. I have searched for fstat on windows, but could only find some android version.

Is there some other way to access file metadata? Is there some other solution to this? I am open to any suggestions and am ok if it sometimes false-flags, as long as it backs up data correctly and doesn't waste resources on backing up everything all the time.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Standard C does not define a way of finding file metadata.  Any solution will therefore use platform-specific calls.  Mac and Linux are near enough the same here.  Windows is a law unto itself.

Comment: MSVC has [`_fstat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?view=msvc-170) with the underscore, being a non-standard C function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fstat` is still the way to do this, but on Windows it's called `_fstat`.  You can check for the `_MSC_VER` macro which will be defined if you're building with MSVC, and if so create a macro alias for `fstat`.

You can do the same for `struct stat` which MSVC calls `struct _stat`:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define fstat(fd,buf) _fstat(fd,buf)
typedef struct _stat stat_struct;
#else
typedef struct stat stat_struct;
#endif
```

Then you can use `fstat` and pass it an argument of type `stat_struct` for the second argument.

I have a decently sized cross platform open source application that uses this technique.

Answer (score 0):

> My plan is to save the last save time in a file and check the real situation of a folder against the data in the file to determine which files need to be backed up or updated.

Ok.

> I was hoping for a cross-platform solution that can be solved with pure C.

If by "pure C" you mean relying on only language features and library functions defined by the C language specification, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.  Pure C (in that sense) has no concept of persistent file metadata such as modification timestamps.  All functions and data structures dealing with such things are extensions or third-party libraries.

You can rely on standard POSIX facilities (such as `fstat()`) for both Linux and Mac, but Windows does not provide that. At least, Windows does not provide it *exactly*.  The Microsoft C library does provide some POSIX compatibility functions, but it somewhat maddeningly uses modified names for them.  In particular, it offers several flavors of [`_fstat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fstat-fstat32-fstat64-fstati64-fstat32i64-fstat64i32?view=msvc-170) (note leading underscore).  With a little bit of macro glue, it should not be too hard to make your program use POSIX `fstat()` on Linux and Mac, and use one of the `_fstat()` flavors on Windows.